# Javascript usage of curly braces

Tags: javascript, curly-braces

I am reading through *Eloquent Javascript* and I had a question regarding this passage and the usage of curly braces:

> This means that curly braces have two meanings in JavaScript. At the start of a statement, they start a block of statements. In any other position, they describe an object. Fortunately, it is almost never useful to start a statement with a curly-brace object, and in typical programs, there is no ambiguity between these two uses.

and this passage:

> Values of the type object are arbitrary collections of properties, and
>   we can add or remove these properties as we please. One way to create
>   an object is by using a curly brace notation.

```
var journal = [
  {events: ["work", "touched tree", "pizza",    
            "running", "television"],    
   squirrel: false},    
  {events: ["work", "ice cream", "cauliflower",    
            "lasagna", "touched tree", "brushed teeth"],    
   squirrel: false},    
  {events: ["weekend", "cycling", "break",    
            "peanuts", "beer"],    
   squirrel: true},    
  /* and so on... */   
];
```

The above code looks like a bunch of properties and their array values. What are the brackets doing? They seem to be grouping each property as an array value and a boolean. Is that what the curly brackets are doing? According to the definition, are they starting a block of statements or are they describing an object? What does it mean to describe an object with curly brackets? Is an object in javascript just a collection of properties where 1 is sufficient to make it an object?

Comment: Think of it like this: The square brackets are for representing arrays, the curly braces are for representing key-value maps.

Comment: these days, it CAN be useful to use them around blocks, since block-level scoping for functions is becoming the default in most browsers. ex: (function(){ 'use strict';{  function f3(){} } alert(typeof f3 === "undefined");}());

Comment: Why am I downvoted? I realize I am new to the community, but I think just because a question is easy doesn't necessarily mean it warrants a downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's only one statement in the code you posted: the declaration of and assignment to `journal`. It is being initialized to an array of objects, each of which has two properties: `events` and `squirrel`. Assuming that the "and so on" continues the pattern, each `events` property is initialized to an array of string values and each `squirrel` property is being initialized to a boolean.

Each pair of (square) brackets defines an array and each pair of curly brackets (braces) define objects. That's what's going on.

As to your question "What does it mean to describe an object with curly brackets?", this is described in the [documentation of JavaScript object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals).

Answer (score 2):

Each bracket here is defining/creating an object.

The brackets are simply to create that object, simple as that. You can just take it for its face value.

[This article](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/) is good reading for *really* getting to the bottom of things (why they are used and of what they are a substitute).